# Can someone fix this issue Visual Studio Code is giving me?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Please help fix the issue shown below.

[image]

Why is VSCode is giving me this message?
It is not making a console window, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and other debug text is displayed in the same window as the output of your program because the project is configured with `"console": "internalConsole"`.

An example of another message you'll see in the debug console would be:

`'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.0-rc.1.20451.14\System.Console.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.`

#### Solutions

1. Don't worry and keep using `internalConsole`.
2. Switch project's console (in `launch.json`) to `externalTerminal` or `integratedTerminal`. This will separate the debug output from the program's output.
   Here's a view with `externalTerminal`:

   [image]
3. Run you program with `dotnet run`

   [image]

Comment: thnx will try that

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue there, it is just letting you know the debugger can only be used in visual studio, which you are using. Try running without debugging (Ctr + F5).

Comment: yeah I tried that, and still did not create a separate console window